# Windows.Forms.Timers tick and button click at the same time in c#

Tags: c#

I have a button and a Windows.Forms.Timers timer1. Both of them have some operations on database. Could couse any problem on Main thread if timer1 tick fired when button click is already operating ?
What is the Main thread response in this case ?
Both of them operates seperately or button click operation blocked by timer1 tick ?

Comment: It depends on the code in your event handler. The easiest way to get a reentrancy would be to put an `Application.DoEvents` somewhere in the event handler code.

Comment: Does the operation entirely block the UI Thread? As if you had `Thread.Sleep()`? So the message loop doesn't process any messages? If it doesn't, the Tick event is raised and the related procedure called. So, better stop the Timer when the same action is triggered somewhere else. Re-enable when the procedure returns.

Comment: Dear Jimi , there is no Thread.sleep() in my app. did a sample application , button click first start timer1. timer1 interval=10ms and timer1 goes to stop in the end of the timer1 process.  After starting timer1 , button click read data from database. I tried to read data at the same time with both timer tick amd button click from the database. It is working properly ! there is not appear a problem.

Comment: I didn't say that you have `Thread.Sleep()` in your code, I asked whether the code you have blocks the UI Thread as `Thread.Sleep()` does. A Timer set to `10ms` is **way** too low, in any case; for querying a database is totally inconsistent: you wouldn't be able to use the GUI. This cannot be the real scenario. -- As mentioned, if your procedure is not fully blocking, i.e., the UI Thread can process messages, the Timer will tick, unless you stop it. The Timer won't Tick only if you cannot use the GUI at all while that procedure is running. BUT the same would apply when the Timer ticks, so...

Comment: Ohh sorry i misunderstood you.  There is noting to blocking UI thread i my app. Yes 10ms is too low but timer operating only one time and then stop. Hard disk a mechamical device and i think it can not have accessed in 10ms. i hope that. So i choose 10ms. Scenario is that first firing button click and button process start to reading database and also firing timer1 and 10ms later timer1 start to read dadabase. button and timer read data only one time. Im am trying to understand what happening if button and timer operate on database  at he same time or very close time. Thx for your advising

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't implementing any async operations, this cannot happen. When an event is raised on the UI thread, whether a Form Timer or a Button Press, the UI is locked for the duration (as the thread handling the rendering is busy doing something else). In the event where you click a button while a timer_tick is running, the UI won't begin processing the button_clicked event until the timer_tick event returns.

If you are implementing any await/async operations or running any background workers, then things get a little more complicated because the timer_tick event could be awaiting a result from a background thread and begin processing the button_clicked event before that has returned. However, unless you are implementing threading yourself this cannot happen.

Comment: Dear Spradlin, i don't have any await/async or background worker. You mean in this case button click and timer tick  can not effect each other because UI is locked Form Timer tick or a Button Press  event in process . Thank you very much

Comment: Dear Spradlin , do you have any idea in case of. if timer and button in different foms.